# R - How to work with and plot time data

Tags: r, time, plot

I have the following data (of which the following is a small sample):

```
times <- c("02:45:00", "02:45:07", "02:45:10", "02:45:20", "02:45:25", "02:45:27",  "02:45:27", "02:45:30", "02:45:32", "02:45:37")
```

I would like to plot these times and be able to have them be in a time variable format if possible.  In the graph, I want to be able to have different time bands in order to create a histogram of the different distribution of times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look into [`strptime`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/strptime.html) to get familiar with the base time format.

Then, something like this might get you started:

```
 hist(strptime(times,"%H:%M:%S"), "secs", freq = TRUE, xlab="seconds")
```

[image]